# When can we write $f(v)dv=f(E)dE$?

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-mechanics

In statistical thermodynamics we write 
$$f(v)\,dv = f(E)\,dE$$

where $v$ is velocity and $E= \frac12mv^2$  is energy

and $f$ refers to the distribution function

Can someone explain the logic behind?

Comment: Abuse of notation $f(v):=f(E(v))$; what happens here is a simple matter of substitution, that is $g:=f\circ\alpha$ with $\alpha(v):=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ then $f(E)dE=f(\alpha(v))\cdot\alpha'(v)dv=g(v)\cdot\alpha'(v)dv$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distribution function has the property:
$f(v) = \frac{dn}{ndv} $
& $f(E) = \frac{dn}{ndE} $
Hence $f(v)dv=f(E)dE=\frac{dn}{n}$